# Magento 2 Backend - Click on the admin user and an error will be output

Tags: magento2.2, error, magento2.2.6

If you click on the administrator user, an error will be output.
Please tell me the solution.

[image]

Below is the error code.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php on line 306

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php on line 306
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(306): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Illegal offset ...', '/var/www/html/m...', 306, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(281): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->applyTabsCorrectOrder(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(238): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->reorderTabs()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-user/Block/User/Edit/Tabs.php(56): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->_beforeToHtml()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(666): Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tabs->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('adminhtml.user....')
#7 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('adminhtml.user....')
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('adminhtml.user....')
#9 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('adminhtml.user....', false)
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('adminhtml.user....', false)
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('left', false)
#12 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#14 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('left', false)
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('left', false)
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('side.col', false)
#17 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#19 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('side.col', false)
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('side.col', false)
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...', false)
#22 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#24 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...', false)
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.conta...', false)
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false)
#27 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#29 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false)
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content', false)
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#32 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#34 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false)
#37 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#39 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false)
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page', false)
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#42 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#44 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#46 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(492): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#49 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(221): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#51 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-user/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Edit.php(49): Magento\Framework\App\View->renderLayout()
#52 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/User/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Edit/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Edit->execute()
#53 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Interceptor->execute()
#54 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(235): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#55 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#56 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#57 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#58 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#59 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#60 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/User/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Edit/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#61 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#62 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#63 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#64 /var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#65 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#66 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#67 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#68 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#69 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#70 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#71 /var/www/html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#72 {main}
```

Comment: did you try with clear cache **php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush** or re-deploy **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f** ??

Comment: I ran the command script at the console, but the problem was not solved.

Is there any other possible means?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue comes from here:

> /var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

Check this plugin

> Infortis/Cgen/Plugin

Disabled it for a mom and see if your issue is fixed. 
If its fixed , than check the event of this module.

Comment: We have disabled the module.
But the situation will not change.
Is there anything else you can think of?

Comment: Did you cleared generated code after you disabled the module ? **rm -r generated/*** ,  **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** , **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** , **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: Yes. I confirmed that the command received from you was processed by cone sole and it was processed correctly, but an error is output still.